# White list in str.replace

Tags: javascript, php, html

i'm using this code to replace everyone who has website link in they name change it to nothing e.g

`Username - Somewebsite.com`  -> `Username -`

For that I use this code:

```
name.replace(/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]*\.com)/g, '');
```

But I want to make it so when user is using my website adress in their name to not remove it e.g

`Username - Mywebsitename.com` -> `Username - Mywebsitename.com`

Comment: Well if I remove it it removes for **someotherwebsite.com** too. I have my link to be whitelisted.

Comment: Hey thanks for reply it should be .com i copied it wrong..

Comment: Saw your comment asking for @adeneo to go on Skype, it's not common for users here to provide that sort of assistance. Try pushing forward on your own with whatever strategy you think is best and post more questions here on Stack Overflow when you get stuck. If your question is clear and well thought out, someone will always be glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest would be to just use a callback for `replace()` and weed out matches on a certain string

```
var mySite = 'Somewebsite.com';

var name   = "Username - Somewebsite.com";

var result = name.replace(/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]*\.com)/g, function(what) {
    return what === mySite ? what : "";
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/4tmq8k4p/)

Comment: Hello thank you very much for reply.
But im using this
`name = name.replace(/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]*\.com)/g, '');`
`name = name.replace(/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]*\.net)/g, '');`
`name = name.replace(/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]*\.us)/g, '');`
`name = name.replace(/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]*\.gg)/g, '');`

my website domain name is: CSGO-Sharks.com . If they use my domain in they name string should do nothing. But if they using like something else like CSGOWild.com it should replace it to nothing.

Comment: Then why not wrap all that strange replacing in an `if` condition, like `if ( name.indexOf("CSGO-Sharks.com") === -1 ) { replace stuff }`

Comment: Hey adeneo, can I add you in skype please?

Answer (score 0):

Nearly pure regex solution:

```
/\s+\-\s+(?!Mywebsite\.com)([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)\.com/i
```

Working example:

```js
var regex = /\s+\-\s+(?!Mywebsite\.com)[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.com/i

var string = 'Username - Somewebsite.com'
var output = 'Username -'
console.log('Match:', string)
console.log('Result:', string.replace(regex, ' -'))
console.log('Correct:', (string.replace(regex, ' -') === output) === true)
console.log('') // new line

var string = 'Username - Mywebsite.com'
var output = 'Username - Mywebsite.com'
console.log('Match:', string)
console.log('Result:', string.replace(regex, ' -'))
console.log('Correct:', (string.replace(regex, ' -') === output) === true)
```

Regex Explanation:

```
/ //-> open regex
  \s+ //-> match one or more spaces
  \- //-> match one literal dash
  \s+ //-> match one or more spaces
  (?!Mywebsite\.com) //-> look ahead & assert next match is not "Mywebsite.com"
  ([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+) //-> match one or more lower or upper case letter, digits, & dot
  \. //-> match literal dot
  c //-> match c
  o //-> match o
  m //-> match m 
/ //-> close regex
i //-> make search case insensitive
```

Look behind would likely have been more ideal for this, but it's not supported in JavaScript.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Not a problem! Consider marking the answer that is closest to what you were looking for as correct by clicking on the grey check mark on the top-left of the post.